# Android drawer shadow shifted

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I added a new activity to my android application **quiz**, in order to implement a navigation drawer with shadow. This drawer shadow had been rendered in fragment `NavigationDrawerFragment` :

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```

However, the shadow was shifted :

[image: shifted drawer shadow] [image: normal drawer shadow]

**Shifted Shadow** vs **Normal Shadow**

The second screenshot comes from an other android project **quizf**, based on a android fragment template. It is created for find out why **quiz** didn't work. By comparing these two projects, I still cannot find out where is the difference. Can someone help ?

---

**quiz's** drawer_main2.xml (shifted)

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccc"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    tools:context="fr.esigelec.cs.quiz.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

**quizf** drawer_main.xml (normal)

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#cccc"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

Comment: yes, we can help you, but please add xml code for both

Comment: please tell me what other xml files should I provide @piotrek1543

Comment: firtst of all, I noticed that you're using different context in both class

Comment: check please Java code for `ListView` in both application

Comment: It works by changing context from `fr.esigelec.cs.quiz.NavigationDrawerFragment` to `.NavigationDrawerFragment` !! :D Thank you !! Could you please put this to the answer field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours layouts are different in `tools:context` attribute:

> **quiz's** drawer_main2.xml (shifted)
>
> ```
> <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:background="#cccc"
>     android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
>     android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
>     android:dividerHeight="0dp"
>     tools:context="fr.esigelec.cs.quiz.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
> ```
>
> **quizf** drawer_main.xml (normal)
>
> ```
> <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
>     android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
>     android:dividerHeight="0dp"
>     android:background="#cccc"
>     tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />
> ```

Try to find if the first one `tools:context` do not cause the problem by changing its value to as in the second one.